# c:url doesn't pre-pend context to url in one of my views

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl, jsp-tags

I'm working in a spring mvc project, I have an issue in one jsp view, c:url is not addong the context on a url, I have every thing working fine, in anothers views c:url works fine, just in one view it does not.

In first i have the following file (called include.jsp):

```
<%@ page session="true"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
```

At starting every view i include the file.

For example I have this view:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/include.jsp"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Registro de Persona</title>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/globalHeaders.jsp"%>
</head>
<body class="skin-blue">
        <!-- a lot of things -->
            <!-- Main content -->
        <!-- a lot of things -->
                                                        <c:if test="${!empty usuariosForm.fotografia}">                                                         <c:set var="fotoUrl" value="${usuariosForm.fotografia}" />
                                                        </c:if>
                                                        <c:if test="${empty usuariosForm.fotografia}">
                                                            <c:set var="fotoUrl" value="/resources/img/320x310.gif" />
                                                        </c:if>
                                                        <label>Foto:</label> <img
                                                            src="<c:url value="${fotoUrl}"/>" alt="Fotografia"
                                                            class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" title="Fotografia" />
                                            <!-- a lot of things more -->
```

and the src of the fotografia image is builded just as expected, adding the context at startint the url.

Now in the following view:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/include.jsp"%>
<header class="main-header">
        <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
<!-- lot of things -->
                <security:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
                            <security:authentication property="principal.nombre" /> <i class="caret"></i></span>
                    </a> 
                    <c:set var="fotoUrl">
                        <security:authentication property="principal.fotografia" />
                    </c:set>
                    <c:if test="${empty fotoUrl}">
                        <c:set var="fotoUrl" value="/resources/img/user.png" />
                    </c:if>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="user-header light-blue">
                                <img src="<c:url value="${fotoUrl}"/>" alt="Fotografia" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" title="Fotografia" />                                   
                                <p>
                                    <security:authentication property="principal.nombre" />
                                    <security:authentication property="principal.apPaterno" />
                                    <security:authentication property="principal.apMaterno" />
                                </p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="user-footer">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Perfil</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <a href="j_spring_security_logout"
                                        class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Salir</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul></li>

                </security:authorize>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Id does not work and th url of image never has the contex of the app

I read somewhere the tag shouldn't be inside another tag and I thouhg the tag of c:url must be outside the security:authorize tag, I tried that way but still no working.

Whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after trying several things, I got a solution, the problem comes from setting the value in fotourl, from the code:

```
<c:set var="fotoUrl">
<security:authentication property="principal.fotografia" />
</c:set>
```

Instead previous code I am now usign:

```
<security:authentication var="fotoUrl" property="principal.fotografia" />
```

And evering works fine.